# Elasticsearch scripted fields. Dynamic param selection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to have a dynamic param based on a value in the document.

I tried so far this here

```
 body: {
            "script_fields": {
                "potentialIncome": {
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "source": "doc.rentPrice.value - params['doc.buyingPrice.value']",
                        "params": {
                            120000: 1200,
                            150000: 1500
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

This throws me following error:

```
type: 'script_exception',
    reason: 'runtime error',
    script_stack: 
     [ 'doc.rentPrice.value - params[\'doc.buyingPrice.value\']',
       '                            ^---- HERE' ],
    script: 'doc.rentPrice.value - params[\'doc.buyingPrice.value\']',
    lang: 'painless'
```

I would like to have params dynamic in a way that the doc value `buyingPrice` decides which value to deduct.

Using ElasticSearch 7.2

---

A complicated and bad way is to use following script

```
if(doc['buyingPrice'].value==120000){return doc['rentPrice'].value-params['120000']}

else if(doc['buyingPrice'].value==150000){return doc['rentPrice'].value-params['150000']}
```

---

The Es object:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "immo",
            "_type": "objects",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "buyingPrice": 120000,
                "rentPrice": 500
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "immo",
            "_type": "objects",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "buyingPrice": 150000,
                "rentPrice": 500
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try without the single quotes.

```
"source": "return (params[String.valueOf(doc.buyingPrice.value)] != null) ? doc.rentPrice.value - params[String.valueOf(doc.buyingPrice.value)] :  0",
                         ^                     ^
                         |                     |
```

Comment: This works in the sense it does not break anymore - but potential income is now always 0. I edited and add the objects

Comment: There you go I fixed the query.

Comment: Hey - can you do me a favor? ;) I have the same issue - now it is a text field. The text field is `doc.region.value` and I have params where the key is a string. How do I do that?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question.