# Elasticsearch: Unable to order results using script_score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field called **price** in my elasticsearch index whose values I need to convert before sorting -

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 1,
          "currency" : "USD",
          "price" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 2,
          "currency" : "INR",
          "price" : 60
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 3,
          "currency" : "EUR",
          "price" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 5,
          "currency" : "MYR",
          "price" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As the `currency field` for each product is different,
I plan to **convert each product's price into USD**,
Using the `script_score` function, as recommended here -
[Elastic Search sort preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058673/elastic-search-sort-preprocessing/32063301)

**I tried the following query -**

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "USD": 1,
                            "SGD": 0.72,
                            "MYR": 0.24,
                            "INR": 0.014,
                            "EUR": 1.12
                        },
                        "source": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**I'm getting an error -**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']",
          "                               ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "products",
        "node": "5-fQ27BhSUKycVJ2SwyH4A",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']",
            "                               ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "doc['price'].value * params.doc['currency']",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "class_cast_exception",
            "reason": "Cannot apply [*] operation to types [java.lang.Long] and [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Strings]."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**Expected product sequence -**
 1. **prod_id 3**, _score 2.24 = `2(price) * 1.12 (USD multiplier)`
 2. **prod_id 1**, _score 1 = `1(price) * 1 (USD multiplier) = 1`
 3. **prod_id 2**, _score 0.84 = `60(price) * 0.014 (USD multiplier)`
 4. **prod_id 5**, _score 0.24 = `1(price) * 0.24 (USD multiplier)`

**Index Mapping -**

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "currency": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "prod_id": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Can someone please help for this use case query?**

**test 1 -**
[image]
**test 2 -**
[image]
**null_pointer_exception -** 
[image]

Comment: The answer you referred is four years ago, so maybe outdated. Try placing `"boost_mode":"replace"` under `function_score`. Read the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query) for more information.

Comment: @ymonad  modified the question with changes to query, moved "boost_mode":"replace" under function_score, now getting script_score query does not support [params],

Comment: `params` should be inside `"script":{"params":...}`. Read the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) for more information.

Comment: @ymonad moved params under script, and the code under source, also removed the function array, now getting a variable not defined error, modified the question again

Comment: `EUR` should be `params.EUR`

Comment: @ymonad No errors now, but getting wrongly sorted results

Comment: Since you are doing `"sort": [{"price": {"order": "desc"}}]`, score calculation of `function_score` is meaningless. you should remove the `sort:[...]`

Comment: Also note that `currency` field should be [keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) if you want to compare equality.

Comment: @ymonad Removed sort property from the query, also the currency field is of keyword datatype - "currency": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      }, I've updated the Query and Added the index mapping to the question

Comment: I think `params.doc['currency']` should be something like`params[String.valueOf(doc.currency)]` as found in this question: [Elasticsearch scripted fields. Dynamic param selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794143/elasticsearch-scripted-fields-dynamic-param-selection)

Comment: @arkuuu `"source": "doc['price'].value * params.[String.valueOf(doc['currency'])]"` -> script_exception

Comment: Well in the question I linked the field was a numeric field. Maybe just try `params[doc['currency']]`? Note that there should be no `.` between `params` and `[`.

Comment: @arkuuu didn't work for either `"source": "doc['price'].value * params.[String.valueOf(doc['currency'])]"` or `"source": "doc['price'].value * params[doc['currency']]"` , updated error screenshots in question :'(

Comment: Maybe `params[doc['currency'].value]` or `params.get(doc['currency'].value)`? Sorry, I'm just guessing here...

Comment: @arkuuu No worries, I'm doing trial and error for a while now haha, null_pointer_exception for both `params[doc['currency'].value]` and `params.get(doc['currency'].value)`

Comment: Your question is a mess. please revert it to question which get result but order is wrong. I got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `currency` has type `text`, it is indexed with [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which converts it to lower case.

That means, when currency is `MYR`, it is indexed as `myr`, so the script should be something like:

```
doc.currency.value == 'myr' ? params.MYR : 1
```

If `currency` is `"type":"keyword"`, then you can use:

```
doc.currency.value === 'MYR' ? params.MYR : 1
```

Comment: any way to shorten this -
`"source" : "doc['price'].value * (doc.currency.value == 'eur'? params.EUR : doc.currency.value == 'myr' ? params.MYR : doc.currency.value == 'inr' ? params.INR : 1)"` cause I will endup having 20-30 currencies :/

Comment: Maybe yes, but please post it as different question.